# Apex get fields of ANY object

Tags: apex, map, sobject

I have a JSON response that returns a List which contains city names. I need to de-duplicate this list. Here is my apex:

```
    global void myLeadsCities(Map<String,Object> inputJsonMap) {
        Set<String> leadCities = new Set<String>();
        List<Object> objs = (List<Object>)inputJsonMap.get('leads');
        for (Object o : objs) {
//console.log(o);  //this returns example: {city=New York} or {city=Boston}, etc...
            //how do I get o.city
            //leadCities.add(o.city);
        }
    }
```

Apex doesn't recognize personName so it fails. How do I read a value from "ANY" Object type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [cast](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_casting.htm) to another Map:

```
for (Object o : objs) {
  Map<String, Object> leadFields = (Map<String, Object>)o;
  String city = (String)leadFields.get('city');
  System.debug(city);
}
```

`Object` (ANY) is the parent of all objects, and you can't really "do" anything with it. You need to cast it to a subtype (Boolean, Map, List, String, whatever) to get useful functionality with it.

You can use `instanceOf` to detect the runtime value of an Object. For `JSON.deserializeUntyped`, it will always be one of `Boolean`, `String`, `Integer`/`Long`, `Double`/`Decimal`, `List<Object>`, or `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: appreciate the explanation. I wish I could upvote it twice :)